# Setting View 1 as a default view page in UIscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm using `UIScrollview` and page control in my application . I have integrated 3 views , `view 0` , `view1` and `view2` in the `UIScroll` view with `page control`. Everything is running fine.

When I run the application , I want `View1` should be the default page , but its showing `view0` as a default page.

Does any one help how to get the `view1` as a default page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set scrollview content offset as (320,0) in viewDidLoad method.

```
 [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0)];
```

Comment: Thanks bro ... Its help :-) Salute to you from my side

Comment: thanks bro...if you are getting answer for your question then accept that answer It helps clean up the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

set the content offset of `UIScrollView`. U added all 3 `views` in the `UIScrollView` but not set the offset of it.

```
scr.contentOffset = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width, 0);
```